# Make achievements dialog a full page

Tags: feature-request, reputation, achievements-dialog

Any reason Recent Achievements isn't available as a full page at `/achievements` or `/reputation` or something?

Pretty much every time I visit SO I look at that dialog. I wonder how many users are like me and have this same workflow multiple times a day: open SO tab, check Achievements icon for new stuff, open the dialog if so, close SO tab. It would be nice to be able to go directly to it. (do y'all have usage metrics on how many users access this dialog, vs other features on the home page?)

[The reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55948/kenwarner?tab=reputation&sort=time) on my profile page is the closest thing I've seen and I guess I could just bookmark that, but even that doesn't show everything that the Achievements dialog shows (btw is there a SO link format like /users/current?tab=reputation that works for any logged in user so I didn't have to link to my own specific page?)

Secondary question: I just discovered SO keyboard shortcuts today. Please make a keyboard shortcut <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to navigate to this new `/achievements` page